# Exporting Images Linked with Survey data, from a GPS to GIS format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps, land-survey, leica-geo-office

We were setting up a workflow system, wherein we attach Survey images to our collected point data (Leica GPS). The same can be viewed in Software like Leica Geo office, but a GIS export of the files (export shapefile option) doesn`t remember the Data - image link.

I have linked the photo to the survey points and later exported it to a shapefile from Leica Geo office 8.0, after importing the raw data.

But the shapefile does not recognise the point-image link.

Any expert advice on the best workflow for preserving the image link till GIS output?

Comment: You have an [tag:arcgis-desktop] tag but make no mention of using that.  In any event, it sounds like you are asking for ideas rather than telling us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Yeah I have edited the qn in such a way to reflect where I was stuck. Also the arcgis-desktop tag was to highlight the preferred GIS data viewer.

Comment: you can have a column with the image path (as text) as a hyperlink. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-hyperlinks.htm#GUID-17542262-D38E-4C6A-967D-62821B02C06C

Comment: @Mapperz I think you should elaborate on this comment a bit and use it as an answer. It makes the most sense to me and is how I have done it in the past, using Trimble products.

Answer (score 1):

What software are you utilizing with the Leica GPS? I know the Leica Zeno Mobile software will export directly to shapefile and has a picture field as well as other available attribute fields available to design a feature library for field collection.

Comment: @ Johnson5144 : We are using Leica SmartWorx Viva running on the CS10 controller

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to help with the SmartWorx Viva software and export from LGO as am not familiar with either. I have been using the Zeno Mobile software on the Leica Zeno 20 for this type of application with success. Have you tried to reach out to Leica's tech support?